# Generating an ID with date and Python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

In QGIS I would like to generate preset IDs (column name: year_id) via the attribute form. Based on the date column "date_start" the corresponding year should be recognized. It should be supplemented with four digits (e.g.: 20240000). If a new object is now added, the corresponding year is to be calculated by plus 1. It is important that each year has a separate counting range. I have now written a Python function that I would like to integrate into the default value in the attribute form of the layer. But so far not successful. What are the errors here? How can I integrate the script into the expression dialog? Here is the script:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import datetime

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def generate_id(datum_start, year_id, feature, parent):
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    year_difference = datum_start.year - current_year
    
    if year_difference == 0:
        base_year = datum_start.year
    else:
        base_year = current_year
    
    base_number = base_year * 10000
    
    max_year_number = 0
    for feat in parent.getFeatures():
        if feat['datum_start'].year == base_year:
            max_year_number = max(max_year_number, feat['year_id'] % 10000)
    
    new_id = base_number + max_year_number + 1
    return new_id
```

Comment: Hi, i don't know what are the errors in your function, but don't try to aggregate features. If you need a max value, compute it with qgis aggregate functions and pass only the max value as argument to your custom function.

Comment: `parent` arg doesn't reference the layer but the current Expression so your `parent.getFeatures()` is clearly wrong. What kind of object is `datum_start`? a String?